# JQuery getting value or length of check_box_tag

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ruby on Rails 3.
I have a form with two questions. I want the second question to show or hide based on the first question's  selection made by user.
Currently the element is returning 0 when it should return a length or value.
So in JS I enter:

```
$("survey_hardware_").find("input[value='IP Phones']:checked").length
```

And this returns 0.

Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#device').change(function(event){
if ($("survey_hardware_").find("input[value='IP Phones']:checked").length ||
  $("survey_hardware_").find("input[value='IP PBX Systems']:checked").length)
{
    $('#phonepbx').css('display', 'inline');
}
else
{
    $('#phonepbx').css('display', 'none');
}
});
});
```

This is the question:

```
<div class="row" id="device">
<ul>1.  What IP hardware does your company frequently sell and/or install?  (select all that apply)<br/>
<li style="display:block;"><%= check_box_tag 'survey[hardware][#{test}]', "IP Phones" %> IP Phones</li>
<li style="display:block;"><%= check_box_tag 'survey[hardware][]', "IP PBX Systems" %> IP PBX Systems </li>
<li style="display:block;"><%= check_box_tag 'survey[hardware][]', "IP Security/Surveillance Systems" %> IP Security/Surveillance Systems</li>
<li style="display:block;"><%= check_box_tag 'survey[hardware][]', "IP infrastructure (cabling, switches...etc.)" %> IP infrastructure (cabling, switches...etc.)</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is the second question I want to show only if question one has 1 or 2 selected.

```
<div class="row" id="phonepbx" style="display:none"> 
<ul>4a.  My customers have their own brand preferences regarding VoIP manufacturers.<br/>
<li><%= f.radio_button(:voip, "1") %>Strongly Agree</li>
<li><%= f.radio_button(:voip, "2") %>Somewhat Agree</li>
<li><%= f.radio_button(:voip, "3") %>Neutral</li>
<li><%= f.radio_button(:voip, "4") %>Somewhat Disagree</li>
<li><%= f.radio_button(:voip, "5") %>Strongly Disagree</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have tried adding a unique id to each selection. The element returns 0 as well. How do I get the length or value of the selection to hide or show a div? Thank you

**EDIT**

I changed the script to this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#survey_hardware_").on('click', function(){
if (($("#survey_hardware_")[0].value == 'IP Phones') || ($("#survey_hardware_")[1].value == 'IP PBX Systems'))
{
    $('#phonepbx').css('display', 'inline');
}
else
{
    $('#phonepbx').css('display', 'none');
}
});
});
```

This will show the div. But not toggle show and hide. Thanks for the information.

**My Solution**

```
function checkHardware() {
    if ($('#device input:checkbox:eq(0)').is(':checked') || $('#device input:checkbox:eq(1)').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#phonepbx').css('display', 'block');
    }

    if ($('#device input:checkbox:eq(2)').is(':checked') || $('#device input:checkbox:eq(3)').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#ipsec').css('display', 'block');
    }

    if ($('#device input:checkbox:eq(0)').is(':checked') == false && $('#device input:checkbox:eq(1)').is(':checked') == false)
    {
        $('#phonepbx').css('display', 'none');
    }

    if ($('#device input:checkbox:eq(2)').is(':checked') == false && $('#device input:checkbox:eq(3)').is(':checked') == false)
    {
        $('#ipsec').css('display', 'none');
    }
```

}

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you changed your original code from `.find()` to `.filter()` it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of problems.

1. The `div` itself won't change. So your listening to plain div `#device` change will never be triggered. Below is from jQuery doc to tell what will send `change` event:

   > The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to `input` elements, `textarea` boxes and `select` elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus. http://api.jquery.com/change/
2. Using `change` is not good. It can only be consumed once and not good for dynamic things. It's better to use `on`

   ```
   $('.some_input').on('change', function(){
     // Do something here
   });
   ```
3. `length` equals to 0 is valid for a blank Array. So your condition will always return true.

Seeing above problems it's hard to provide precise solution. Please refactor and check what problems will left.

**Update**

It's a bit hard to figure out the layout. But my own suggestion is to add a `data-target` attribute on checkbox and listen to their own change.

Given such checkbox

```
check_box_tag 'survey[hardware][]', "IP PBX Systems", 
  data: {target: "#question2"}, class: 'question_1_check_box"
```

And such question 2 div

```
<div id="question2">question 2 content</div>
```

Then

```
$('.question_1_checkbox').on('change', function(){
  $(this.data('target')).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Good catch on the `change` event on `div`, somehow I missed that and only noticed the selector problem.  I guess then my "incomplete" answer would be point 4 in this list :)

Comment: I changed the script. See edit. Now I need it to toggle. I was thinking of specifying the array number in the .on('click', function() but do not know how to specify it. Any ideas?

Comment: I've updated answer, this solution should be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

In the following line:

```
$("survey_hardware_").find("input[value='IP Phones']:checked").length
```

you are selecting a DOM element `survey_hardware_`.  The selector is valid but I don't believe that you have `survey_hardware_` element.  You probably have an element with `id` or `class` by that name.

So, if you are selecting an element with `survey_hardware_` id then use the `#` selector as follows:

```
$("#survey_hardware_").find("input[value='IP Phones']:checked").length
```

Refer [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for other other possible selectors and their usage.